# Image not correctly pushing height of parent div

Tags: html, css

I want a parent div to be the height of the child image, like so:

```
<div class="container one">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
</div>
```

The div should be exactly 250px tall. For Illustration, I created a **JSFiddle** [here](http://jsfiddle.net/m6qwwfnc/2/).

Now what is actually happening in FF and Chrome is that the div is just a bit *taller*, maybe 3 to 5 pixels.

I would like to avoid having to do nesting with unnecessary purely cosmetic markup like

```
<div class="container one">
    <div class="inner">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/250x250" />
    </div>
</div>
```

or similar.

I feel like this is horribly obvious but I just can't make any sense of it.

Comment: Thats the way to assign multiple class names..?

Comment: Change container one to container_one or something with 1 word  make it size 250 250 in css.. In image css give display block .. Height width 100%..

Comment: Class inner you are missing a end quote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<img>` is an inline element and adds that extra space below due to that fact. Fix it with

```
img {
  display: block
}
```

Comment: It makes sense when your image is on the same line with your text, so the space below is used by letters like g, q, p (descenders).